# like button not appearing

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

So this is kind of strange to me, hopefully somebody can help me out.

When I add this code below to a html page and then open it, the like button does not appear. But when I do it in jsfiddle it works http://jsfiddle.net/wZFss/ Anybody got any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks, J

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.diabolotricks.net" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<p>helloworld</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so how did you finally make it working ?

Answer (score 1):

You have your doc type set to xhtml 1.1 and your using the html5 button code.

You will either need to use, iframe button, xfbml button or change your doc type to html5.

refer to: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: I tried with the iframe and xfbml buttons, still couldn't get it to work. Changed the doctype I still couldn't get it to work. Apologies if I being a dumb newbie.

Comment: try the fbml version again, but add this as the html tag

<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

Comment: if that still fails you may need to post a bug to facebook about the local your using as the sdk. 'en_GB'

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working, here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/9UzAD/ before I tell Facebook